# Can't connect to Pusher from .NET application

Tags: c#, .net, frontend, pusher

I am trying to connect to the Pusher service from a .NET application and connecting to the Pusher service is never successful. I have followed step by step how to connect to the service, but nothing happens.

Code:

```
Pusher pusher = new Pusher("APP KEY", new PusherOptions
{
    Encrypted = true,
    Cluster = "us2"
});

pusher.Connected += Pusher_Connected;
pusher.ConnectionStateChanged += Pusher_ConnectionStateChanged;
pusher.Error += Pusher_Error;
var state = await pusher.ConnectAsync();
Console.WriteLine($"Current state: {state}");
Console.WriteLine(pusher.Channels.Count);
Console.ReadKey();
```

NOTES: Obviously I change the APP_KEY for my secret key

The library I use is this: https://github.com/pusher/pusher-http-dotnet

Comment: What error you get?

Comment: Does it even compile? I can't find a constructor for `Pusher` with that signature.

Comment: Yes, it gets compilded, but when the application starts, it doesn't get connected:(

Comment: Is the only constructor available using PusberClient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already managed to connect, the problem was that if I used the "await" to wait to connect or subscribe to a channel, nothing ever happened, but if I did it synchronously, it was possible to connect.